# write error for rmem_max on Angstrom

Tags: udp, sysctl, angstrom

I am trying to tune the UDP receive and transmit buffer size. According to my real time application needs, I need to configure the Tx buffer as 6 bytes and Rx buffer as 22 bytes.
I am running Angstrom on a ARM A9 processor. (Altera cyclone v soc). 
The client and server are communicating over WiFi in adhoc mode.

```
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# cat rmem_max
163840
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# sysctl -w rmem_max=22
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/rmem_max: No such file or directory
```

The file is located at the path  `/proc/sys/net/core` , however the `stat` is looking for the file at path `/proc/sys/`

I have also tried the following :

```
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=22
sysctl: setting key "net.core.rmem_max": Invalid argument
net.core.rmem_max = 22
```

Does anyone have a hand on this problem?

The purpose of tuning the buffer sizes is because, I do not want to queue up the packets in the buffers. It is ok to overwrite the old packet with new packets, every time the call to `recvfrom` and `sendto` is made.

Edit:

A little more debugging to this issue, I found out that the minimum bytes I can set to this buffer is 2240 bytes.

```
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 2238 > rmem_max
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 2239 > rmem_max
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 2240 > rmem_max
root@cyclone5:/proc/sys/net/core# cat rmem_max
2240
```

Is there anyway to reduce this number, to as low as 22 bytes ?